# Localization for peruvian spanish Android

Tags: android, localization

I wondering about localizations in Android. Is it possible to localize for Peruvian spannish for instance? Lets say I want my app in Spanish (Spain) and Spanish (Peru). How can I accomplish this?

Thankful for advice!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that by first putting all you texts in a XML file (see [Using Resources for Localization](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html#using-framework)) and than create to folders, one for that Spain Spanish and one for the Peru Spanish.

```
/res/values-es-ES
/res/values-es-rPE
```

Comment: es-PE doesn't work for me. Are you sure about this? Maybe it should be valures-es-rPE?